# Firebase Storage - GCP Storage Security confusion

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

So I have some .zip files that are onlly downloadable by certain users, I saw that I have Signed Urls in GCS, in Firebase Storage I have the .getDownloadLink() tied with security rules. Now I would prefer the signed URL approach since I can make links expire there.

The problem is what does prevent a User from simply grabbing my Credentials and calling the getDownloadLink() to overwalk my Signed URL approach and share a infinite lasting link to others?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how to prevent your keys from being stolen and used without your permission to distribute your data.

Is important to know how you can distribute your access to your other colleagues because when you are using singned url o other link sahring method nothing guarantee that the people can't re-share the information.

The most simple solution is that you try to not share credentials through insecure channels and not share credentials with unauthorized people.

You can check this [ARTICLE](https://security.berkeley.edu/education-awareness/cybersecurity-best-practices/security-tips/protecting-your-credentials) with more recommendations for securing your credentials

In this article you can find more information about what you can do and what you need to avoid

The main topics in that page are

- How are credentials stolen?
- What can I do to protect my account information?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you enable [bucket policy only](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-policy-only), that will disable getDownloadLink; however, you'll lose object level ACLs as noted in the docs.